# Writing generated numbers in text file in Python

Tags: python, random, numbers

So I tried browsing other posts, and even asked a friend before resorting to actually asking here. I have a homework assignment which calls for me to create a program in Python, that generates random numbers based on how many numbers a user inputs. For example, if they input that they want to generate 5 numbers... the program will do just that. Now my issue is that I created the following:

```
import random

def main():
    howMany = 0
    numbers = 0


    howMany = int(input('How many numbers would you like to generate?: '))

    infile = open ('rand_write.txt', 'w')

    for n in range(1,howMany):
        numbers = random.randint(1,115)
    infile.write(str(numbers))
    infile.close()
main()
```

Everything works alright, until it's time to actually get the 5 numbers onto a text file. I can't... for the life of me.. figure out just what I'm doing wrong. The program writes to the text file, but it only writes a random number, not 5. I would greatly appreciate any pointers and guidance in figuring out what I should do to solve this issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting `numbers` in your `for` loop:

```
for n in range(1,howMany):
    numbers = random.randint(1,115)
```

Instead, you want to make a list called `numbers` as such:

```
numbers = []
for n in range(1,howMany):
    numbers.append(random.randint(1,115))
```

And then use `'\n'.join(map(str, numbers))` to convert to a string and then write it as you did before:
import random

```
def main():
    howMany = 0
    numbers = []


    howMany = int(input('How many numbers would you like to generate?: '))

    infile = open ('rand_write.txt', 'w')

    for n in range(1,howMany):
        numbers.append(random.randint(1,115))
    infile.write('\n'.join(map(str, numbers)))
    infile.close()
main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up modifying the infile.write line with the newline. You helped me to realize that the numbers were being written over. Then I also noticed that my infile.write line was outside of my for loop, that gave me the numbers just as I wanted them on the text file. Thank you again for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong. You need to put tab in front of `infile.write(str(numbers))` to make sure that it gets execute in each loop. Otherwise you end up just writing the last number.

You may also want to write some separator between the numbers.

Finally you may want to make just one call to generate the random numbers as follows:

```
numpy.random.random_integers(1,115, howMany)
```

Comment: Given that numbers is set to an integer, it's hard to guess the intent of the original poster. Additionally you're wrong about the flushing - by default the system buffer will be used when writing to disk.